# How to run all tabs in Google Chrome at startup?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to run two tabs in Google Chrome at startup.  On first tab I've got a slideshow on second I've got player with internet radio playing.

Everything works fine until Google Chrome v47.
I found solution for that version: there was a flag #enable-plugin-power-saver

But Google Chrome v48 doesn't have that flag.

Maybe someone knows how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome address bar, go to

```
chrome://settings/
```

[image]

Then in the **On Startup** section, select **Open a specific page or set of pages**

Click the **Set Pages** Link and add both of your URLs in the boxes that you want Chrome to start up with.

[image]

Comment: Ok. My question was not precise. The problem is with second tab it doesn't autoplay audio. You need to click on that tab to start playing.

Comment: OK gotcha... I'll see what I can figure out